# Japanese language: Exercises for learning adverbs and their usage

Tags: japanese, exercises

I am looking for a book that has plenty of exercises for Japanese adverbs.

I already have an excellent book by Taeko Kamiya [The Handbook of Japanese Adjectives and Adverbs](https://books.google.com/books/about/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E_%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E%E3%83%8F%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%96%E3%83%83.html?id=Em9hfd5cAAQC&redir_esc=y&hl=en). While it provides detailed explanations on meaning and usage, unfortunately, it does not have enough practice materials.

I would prefer a traditional book, but online resources would be helpful as well.

Comment: What languages can these books be in? Only English?

Comment: English or Japanese would be the best options. However, as long as the answer key is provided any language will suffice. I just need a lot of practice.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any other books like Taeko Kamiya's [*The Handbook of Japanese Adjectives and Adverbs*](http://www.kodanshausa.com/books/9781568364162/), at least not in English. There are books with Japanese grammar exercises in English, for example:

- [*Modern Japanese Grammar Workbook*](https://www.routledge.com/Modern-Japanese-Grammar-Workbook/McGloin-Hudson-Nazikian-Kakegawa/p/book/9780415270939) by Naomi McGloin, M. Endo Hudson, Fumiko Nazikian and Tomomi Kakegawa (Routledge, 2014).
- [*Basic Japanese: A Grammar and Workbook*](https://www.routledge.com/Basic-Japanese-A-Grammar-and-Workbook/Hamano-Tsujioka/p/book/9780415498562) by Shoko Hamano and Takae Tsujioka (Routledge, 2011).
- [*Intermediate Japanese: A Grammar and Workbook*](https://www.routledge.com/Intermediate-Japanese-A-Grammar-and-Workbook/Tsujioka-Hamano/p/book/9780415498593) by Takae Tsujioka and Shoko Hamano (Routledge, 2012).

While these books contain exercises that focus on adverbs, these exercises take up only a small part of the book.

There are also a number of exercises on adverbs (and adjectives) in the German [*Übungsbuch zur japanischen Grammatik*](http://www.iudicium.de/katalog/433-6.htm) (IUDICIUM, 1998).

For books focusing on adverbs, you're better served with books in ... *Chinese*:

- [日语副词例解](https://www.amazon.co.uk/%E6%97%A5%E8%AF%AD%E5%89%AF%E8%AF%8D%E4%BE%8B%E8%A7%A3-Japanese-%E5%BB%BA%E5%8D%8E-%E6%9D%8E-ebook/dp/B072MJN4PX/) by 建华 李. (Amazon UK claims that this is a "Japanese edition", but the explanations are in Chinese.)
- [日语副词例解词典](https://www.amazon.co.uk/%E6%97%A5%E8%AF%AD%E5%89%AF%E8%AF%8D%E4%BE%8B%E8%A7%A3%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8-%E6%9D%8E%E6%99%B6/dp/B0062NIIOO/) by 李晶 (see also on [Amazon.cn](https://www.amazon.cn/gp/switch-language/product/B0062NIIOO?ie=UTF8&language=en_CN)).
- [便携日语语法书:副词](https://www.amazon.co.uk/%E4%BE%BF%E6%90%BA%E6%97%A5%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%AD%E6%B3%95%E4%B9%A6%EF%BC%9A%E5%89%AF%E8%AF%8D/dp/B00DMS2YIS/) (see also on [Amazon.cn](https://www.amazon.cn/%E4%BE%BF%E6%90%BA%E6%97%A5%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%AD%E6%B3%95%E4%B9%A6-%E5%89%AF%E8%AF%8D/dp/B00DMS2YIS/)).

However, these books are either reference works or grammar books without exercises.

That does not mean you can't make any exercises. One way of creating exercises is taking example sentences from books like these and turn them into [cloze tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloze_test). You can add such cloze tests to a spaced repetition system such as Anki.

Comment: My problem is that Anki and other SRS apps do not work for me. I am a rare case of a tactile (kinaesthetic) learner. I have to write everything down. I also learn the best when I can absorb huge amounts of data, so I do not want to be stuck with the same 100 sentences.

Comment: When I put cloze tests (or vocabulary) on flashards, I force myself to write down the answers while reviewing. Would that be sufficient to add an kinaesthetic aspect to spaced repetition?